# Is there any way to restore deleted core block in Drupal 8?

Tags: blocks, 8

How to restore core/menu or other programmatically created blocks if they have been deleted in D8?

I remember in D6 and D7 was no possibility to delete programmatically created blocks. 
But D8 allows to delete any block. If I delete custom block, I can create it again manually, but if I delete for example Page Title block, there is no way to return page title block to my site.

Comment: a) "if I delete for example Page Title block, there is no way to return page title block to my site" is not true, b) if the block was not created programmatically but was a config then you can simply import it again(you have to have the config module installed so you get the import/export UI).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you delete some code block in /admin/structure/block

You just need to go on **Place block** and add block again.

[image: Place Block Screenshot]

Also Page Title block you can delete and return like this.

In drupal 8 every think is block, menu even a page title.

[image]